# Passing SSRS parameter into Query as parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

Recently there is one situation in SSRS , Where I am not able to figure it out correct logic for my requirement ,can someone please help me out what is the problem in my logic.

I am trying to pass the parameter value into SSRS dataset query. Please refer the query below. When I am trying to execute the query manually it runs but when I pass parameter in it, not providing me the desired output please refer the screenshot where I executed the query in SSMS.

DataSet Query

---

```
Select * from(
SELECT     @Defaulter_Type AS Priority_Count, Priority
FROM         Quality_Portal_Data_Fact_Graph)  temp
```

---

SQL Query

---

```
SELECT [NEW_PID_2],[Priority_1] 
  FROM [OneWindowPRD].[dbo].[Quality_Portal_Data_Fact_Graph]
```

---

Although, I figure it out one thing that when I am trying to pass parameter in it. It is passing the value with single cort because of which it is showing data is below mentioned form.

[image: output of the query when I pass parameter]

Can someone please suggest What will I do to remove these single cort.
Please suggest any other method or logic to select the column of the query which is given by user

I already tried SUBSTRING its not working. Please refer the screenshot

SELECT     QUOTENAME(SUBSTRING(@Defaulter_Type, 2, LEN(@Defaulter_Type) - 2)) AS Count_Priority
FROM         Quality_Portal_Data_Fact_Graph

[image]

[image]

[image]

The parameter I am trying to pass in the query is the column_name which is passed by user, it is single value column. Please refer screenshot is someone have any suggestion or other approach

Comment: Define "it is not working".

Comment: Query executed successfully but the data from backend not coming means because of single corts it is not working

Comment: What is a "single cort"?  If the query executed successfully why is it "not working",are you not getting the results you are after? If you aren't, why aren't they correct? We can't see what you see, or read your mind, so you need to explain (in detail) what the problem is.

Comment: not working means the query is not giving me desired output, it is giving me the output that is shown in my screenshot. As per my understanding I think the problem is coming in this situation is that the parameter value is coming with corts, is there anyway by which I can remove them

Comment: Are you trying to say "quotes"?

Comment: I've still no idea what "corts" is. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+corts) says it's the plural of cort, which is a Pen, Sty or Stable used by Livestock; that is clearly not relevant here. The image you have provided is from SSMS, not SSRS, so doesn't explain the problem.

Comment: sorry that is 'quotes' not 'corts' my mistake, can someone please suggest any idea how can I extract data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(1000) =
'
Select * from(
SELECT     ' + QUOTENAME(@Defaulter_Type) + ' AS Priority_Count, Priority
FROM         Quality_Portal_Data_Fact_Graph)  temp
'

EXEC (@sql)
```

This uses dynamic SQL to build a query string using your parameter as a column name. It then executes that query to produce your result set.

Your query as it currently is will just select the value of `@Defaulter_Type` as the value of the field `Priority_Count` for every row.

Additionally, if your parameter is encased in quotes that you want to remove, use:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(1000) =
'
Select * from(
SELECT     ' + QUOTENAME(SUBSTRING(@Defaulter_Type, 2, LEN(@Defaulter_Type) - 2)) + ' AS Priority_Count, Priority
FROM         Quality_Portal_Data_Fact_Graph)  temp
'

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Yes I am trying to pass value similarly that is mentioned in above query but the data came with quotes because of which desired result is not coming. Parameter value by default came with single quotes I am trying to remove them do you have any suggestion to remove them

Comment: Have you tried the code in my answer? If the parameter is actually coming with quotes as part of the value, you could try `QUOTENAME(SUBSTRING(@Defaulter_Type, 2, LEN(@Defaulter_Type) - 2))`.

Comment: Its not working I did same thing earlier its not working

Comment: I looked at your screenshot, and it doesn't look like you've used what I posted correctly, e.g., I don't see the `EXEC (@sql)` step.

Comment: Chris the screenshot which i post is after execution of query

Comment: I'm just looking at the picture where you've typed `QUOTENAME(SUBSTRING`, etc. in the query, but you haven't used dynamic SQL as I have done? If you input everything I have written, from `DECLARE @sql` to `EXEC (@sql)`, you should get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the value of a parameter in a dataset but it is not being used as a parameter in a Where clause, then you don't need it in your SQL dataset, simply add it as an additional column on your SSRS report.  If, however, you need it as a parameter, you can address it as  @Defaulter_Type in your WHERE clause.
[New addition for clarity)
@arpit-sharma
I'm afraid I'm unclear on what you are trying to achieve. Can you try something basic like this in the back end (SSMS):

```
Declare @Pid2 VarChar(10)
Set @NewPid = '0'

SELECT
    [Priority_1]
    ,[New_PID_2]
    ,[Project_Ending_3]
    ,[PSU_Status_4]
    ,[Project_Profile_5]
    ,[eUPP_Status_6]
    ,[iPMS_Setup_7]
    ,[PM_EO_8]
FROM [OneWindowPRD].[dbo].[Quality_Portal_Data_Fact_Graph]
WHERE [New_PID_2] = @NewPid
```

The PID column *looks* like what you are trying to filter on, and if so, the SQL above should do it, provided a valid value in the variable.

Comment: Not working craig, see I am trying to use that value in other query as select parameter from table_name. Please suggest anything else